# Not Displaying Complete View in UITabbarController with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xib

In My Application using UINavigationcontroller and UITabbarcontroller Dynamically and adding views like

[UINavigationController inside of UITabBarController issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356819/uinavigationcontroller-inside-of-uitabbarcontroller-issues)
in this way . I am able to got both UITabbarController and UINavigationController. Both are works fine. **But My issue is Here View Not displaying complete as show in XIB. For example i added a UIButton in XIB at the point (110,380). It wont display in IOS Device.**[image]

**The Above image is My XIB here Button Below is not displaying in IOSDevice**

[image]

Please any one help in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mashallah , Doing great job for Muslims in abroad :) .

Comment: Kindly Approve the Answer if it solved for issue .

Comment: Shukriya @munibsiddiqui Bhai,I will try your answer I will get back to you

Comment: Koi masla Nae Brother , Any time :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to for Nib File , On right side in utility view go to attribute inspector.

Now Set Top bar : Navigation Bar

Bottom Bar : tab Bar

And then design your view .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder try to set bottom bar to Tab Bar.[image: Metrics]